# Spring nested autowiring of generic throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to autowire a generic type into a different generic type in the constructor? I currently have a structure like this:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {
@Autowired
ServiceA<Integer> servicea;

}
```

and the services:

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ServiceA<S> {
  private final ServiceB<S,String> dependentServiceB;

  public ServiceA (ServiceB<S,String> dependentServiceB){
     this.dependentServiceB = dependentServiceB;
  }
}

@Configuration
public class ServiceBConfig {
  @Bean
  ServiceB<Integer,String> serviceBwithInt (){
      return new ServiceBImplInt();
  }

  @Bean
  ServiceB<Long,String> serviceBwithLong (){
      return new ServiceBImplLong();
  }

}
```

Now if I try to autowire the ExampleService class somewhere else, it throws a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException containing "No qualifying bean of type '....ServiceB< ? >' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: serviceBwithInt ,serviceBwithLong".

Is this possible to solve it like this or do I have to implement subclasses of ServiceA for each of the different generic types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how type erasure works, both of those beans are eligible to be injected simply because *Java* would accept both of those as valid arguments to the constructor.

If you want to be explicit about which is injected, use a `@Qualifier`.

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ServiceA<S> {
  private final ServiceB<S,String> dependentServiceB;

  public ServiceA (@Qualifier("serviceBWithInt")ServiceB<S,String> dependentServiceB){
     this.dependentServiceB = dependentServiceB;
  }
}
```

If you can't be explicit about which bean you want, you may want to reconsider adding generics here.  There are niche reasons to want to do this in the first place, and the flow of dependency injection is still wholly predictable, even if you don't control the lifecycle of the objects.

Comment: Ok but if I sometimes need ServiceA<Int> and sometimes ServiceA<Long> I need to create subclasses like ServiceAInt extends ServiceA<Int> and ServiceALong extends ServiceA<Long>, right? Or what did you mean about reconsidering using generics?

Comment: I've seldom seen benefit coming from using a generic *component*.  I've seen lots and lots of benefits from having a component have generic methods, but the component itself?  Not sold.  It's led to pain points like this where you're getting tripped up on a Java-ism.